# How to generate a new partition for every 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Hello and thank you in advance for any help provided.

I have something like the below:

```
Name Flag
AAA   1
AAA   2
AAA   3
AAA   1
AAA   2
BBB   1
BBB   2
BBB   3
BBB   4
BBB   3
BBB   1
BBB   2
```

I would like to generate a column called Grp with the desired output as follows:

```
Name Flag Grp
AAA   1    1
AAA   2    1
AAA   3    1
AAA   1    2
AAA   2    2
BBB   1    1
BBB   2    1
BBB   3    1
BBB   4    1
BBB   3    1
BBB   1    2
BBB   2    2
```

Comment: It seems that the order of rows in the input table matters to you. In this case, you should also have a unique column (or combination of columns) where you can store this order.

Comment: Good day iskan, In order to get what you need you can simply use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name , Flag  ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))`, but noticed Razvan comment. For most cases it make no sense to have duplicate rows in the database. If you really eed duplicate rows (fully duplicated on all columns) then you can simply store single column and add another tinyint column where you can add the number of the duplicates - it will save you a lot of space and improve most processing

Answer (score 1):

You can use window function :

```
select t.*, 
       sum(case when flag = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by name order by ?) as Grp
from table t;
```

`?` use ordering column that specifies table ordering instead,.